# Best Practices For Developing Complex Web Pages With JavaScript And jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I just finished a project that uses ASP.NET MVC, jQuery and jQueryUI. One of the pages I wrote is still bugging me because I ended up writing a lot of client-side code for event handlers and it grew out of control due to the complexity of the interactions of the controls on the page and their states (the page is very interactive and has a google docs feel to it). My question is what best practices are available for client-side development (specifically using jQuery & jQueryUI) that have complex interactions (like google docs or yahoo's mail client)? My biggest complaint I had with my code is that for almost all my event handlers, I ended up writing a lot of if statements that executed code based on the states of other controls on the page. It seems like there has to be a way to handle this in a more controlled manner.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific as to the style of code you are currently using.

Comment: I always do large project in object literals, in an "MVC" sort of layout, calling different functions, views, models etc from a main controlling function. Others probably have their methods, but just writing a bunch of event handlers just does'nt cut it unless it's a small manageable website.

Comment: Can you afford some more round trips and take some of it server side, if so there's a thing called the presenter pattern.

Comment: I don't have a style as far as I understand. I use jQuery to attach event handlers to controls on the page in the dom ready event and then handle the events with a lot of JavaScript. The setup is really simple. It's the fact that I have to write so much JavaScript just to deal with something as simple as a mouse click. Worse, if certain conditions are in place (like text being in an input field), the mouse click is handled differently. I felt like I was repeating myself in many places in the code but with slight variations.

Comment: @adeneo I agree. I used a lot of event handlers and am looking for a way to manage the events. Do you have an example using your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the more modular you make things the easier it will be to put together a complex application. Break things down in to discrete components that do just one thing (single responsibility) and have clearly defined APIs to interact with other parts of the system. It sounds simple in theory but, in practice, you really need to put a lot of thought in to the architecture of your app before you get started writing any code.

John Papa's [course on Single Page Applications](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spa) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot from going through ['project silk'](http://silk.codeplex.com/):

> Project Silk provides guidance for building cross-browser web
>   applications with a focus on client-side interactivity.

From the short description you gave, it seems you mainly have issues with how certain parts of your application communicate with others. It sounds you have it quite tightly coupled.
[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404091.aspx) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

There are many options when deciding to choose client side framework.

go through all projects on the [TODOMVC](http://todomvc.com/) project.

I would choose AngularJS for small-medium apps, and GWT for much bigger apps (ASPNET as server side)